# Enabling HANDLE_PRAGMA_PACK_WITH_EXPANSION

Tags: c, gcc, pragma

I'd like gcc to process `pack` pragmas such as the following:

```
#define _CTR_PACKING 4
#pragma pack(push, _CRT_PACKING)
```

MSVC allows this kind of construction by default.

Clang [enabled this behavior](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140217/099508.html) via `-fms-extensions`.

Searching for a gcc equivalent, I found references to macros `HANDLE_PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH_POP` and `HANDLE_PRAGMA_PACK_WITH_EXPANSION`, but even after adding them via `-DHANDLE_PRAGMA_PACK_WITH_EXPANSION=1` or as environment variables, gcc still does nothing.

How can I make gcc behave as MSVC and Clang with `-fms-extensions`?

Answer (score 1):

The gcc macro `HANDLE_PRAGMA_PACK_WITH_EXPANSION` is a macro used by gcc target to indicate whether it supports expansion of macros in pragma directive, it's not a switch to enable on the fly.

Instead, you can use standard C's `_Pragma` operator, it translate into the compiler's pragma directives, and it supports macro expansion since it's part of the language. This is an example:

```
#define STR(s) #s
#define _CTR_PACKING 1

#define PACKSTR(x) STR(pack(x))

_Pragma(PACKSTR(_CTR_PACKING))
```